# Xpath fetching value for Namespace

Tags: xml, xpath

This is the reference XML.

```
<abc:respone xmlns:abc="abc.def.org" operation="POST-create-endpoint">
   <link type="application/xml" href="http://www.xyz.org" rel="related" />
   <messages>
      <abc:message type="ERROR" code="123">
         <value>this is error code</value>
      </abc:message>
   </messages>
</abc:respone>
```

Have to fetch 'value' which is 'this is error code'. If there is no type of 'ERROR' or no tag 'value', then have to return blank. I'm new to xpath language, please help.

Comment: What language are you using to run the XPath processor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use element names when you have namespaces you need to *register* namespaces by mapping a prefix to them and using that prefix in your XPath expression, as noted in the answer by @MartinHonnen. That is implementation dependent, so it's not possible to tell you how to do it unless you tell us what language you are using to run XPath.

But, independent of the language you are using, you can *ignore* namespaces by not using element names as selectors. This is not always recommended because it may lead to conflicts when you have elements with the same names in different namespaces. But to just extract a value from a document such as the one you are using, it may be a solution. You select *all* elements using wildcards such as `*`, `node()`, etc. and then restrict the result set by using a predicate that tests for the local name. In your case you can use this expression:

```
/*[local-name()='respone']
   /*[local-name()='messages']
      /*[local-name()='message'][@type = 'ERROR']
        /*[local-name()='value']
            /text()
```

(check if the local names are correct before using it - is it really `respone` or `response`?)

Comment: tried this expression and is saying 'no match'. If I try with the //*[local-name()='message'][@type = 'ERROR'] then giving entire tag <abc:message type="ERROR" code="123"><value>this is error code</value></abc:message>

Comment: Tried with the expression '//*[local-name()='message'][@type = 'ERROR']/*[local-name()='title']/text()' and worked. Thanks for the input. Please correct me if any modifications required.

Answer (score 1):

You can select `string(/abc:respone/messages/abc:message[@type = 'ERROR']/value)`. Note that you need some way to declare the namespace bound to the `abc` prefix, how you do that depends on the XPath API you use.